# How to change Android emulator path in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, emulation

I've been trying to develop a mobile app in visual studio 2017 with Xamarin. Everything was going fine until I noticed a message in the output window that my Android emulator is out of date. I followed the instructions to update and now I can't debug.  I get the following messages in the output window:

- Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started
- PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for x86 cpu

I read somewhere that, in the new version, the emulator path changes from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.EXE to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE. I cannot find an option to inform visual studio of the new path.  Nor can I get the Xamarin Live Player to pair with my phone. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Open up powershell and run the same command line the emulator starts just fine:
PS C:> & '.\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.exe' -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Andro
id_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 5803 ms

And if I press F5 in Visual Studio while I have the emulator running (started via powershell) it connects fine to it and loads the application.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/252854/unable-to-start-android-emulator-from-within-visua.html

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up uninstalling the mobile development module in visual studio and reinstalling.